# how to add javascript function from INSERT HYPERLINK

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a portal's home page and on that page I want to put this but Its not allowing me to put this address and treating this as invalid address..I tried putting the following statement by EDIT HTML but when the page comes its not clickable. How to add this?

```
<a href="javascript:openDialog('/SitePages/NewReq.aspx')">New Requisition</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off just specifying a class to your a tag and then adding click event through JQuery.

Try this:

On Page

```
<a class="newReqLink">New Requisition</a>
```

In Jquery

```
 $('a.newReqLink').click(function(){ 
       window.openDialog('/SitePages/NewReq.aspx');  
 });
```

**Note:** Written, not tested.